# What is the approrpriate use of Continuity Correction when performing Mann-Whitney U analysis with small (n= 4) & discrete samples?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am using Mann-Whitney U analysis (through R (whilst attempting to justify [STATISTICA] outputs).

The data do not conform to a normal distribution, are discrete and are small in sample size (n = 4). Example (there are data for T1,2, 5, 6, 7, & 8 in complete dataset):

```
T3  T4
75  0
66  2
25  3
21  33
```

Data are UVC Fish counts. Each 4 samples result in the sampling of a single 'transect' and the analysis is to test for significance between each transect (n= 8) within the total data. The project base do not have access to R (rural area) and run the statistical package STATISTICA. I, however, do have access to R and am attempting to understand the output of STATISTICA to advise on the correct 'p' value to report (support for STATISTICA is minimal). Example:

[image]

For efficiency, and save me running 64 independent MWU tests to create a matrix, i run the following code:

```
   d<-my.data
groups <- unique( d$group )
MWU<-outer( 
  groups, groups, 
  Vectorize( function(g1,g2) {
    wilcox.test( 
      d$value[ d$group == g1 ], 
      d$value[ d$group == g2 ],
      paired=FALSE,
      exact=FALSE,
      correct=TRUE
    )$p.value
  } )
)
MWU
```

my.data =

```
group   value
group 1 10
group 1 9
group 1 11
group 1 10
group 2 16
group 2 75
group 2 0
group 2 0
group 3 75
group 3 66
group 3 25
group 3 21
group 4 0
group 4 2
group 4 3
group 4 33
group 5 16
group 5 19
group 5 31
group 5 20
group 6 15
group 6 7
group 6 26
group 6 33
group 7 20
group 7 30
group 7 29
group 7 133
group 8 14
group 8 8
group 8 20
group 8 15
```

Output:

```
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
[1,] 1.00000000 1.0000000 0.02940105 0.3094241 0.02940105 0.3094241 0.02940105 0.30942406
[2,] 1.00000000 1.0000000 0.24252556 1.0000000 0.38074574 0.6631172 0.19126699 0.88454944
[3,] 0.02940105 0.2425256 1.00000000 0.1123512 0.11235120 0.3123214 1.00000000 0.03038282
[4,] 0.30942406 1.0000000 0.11235120 1.0000000 0.31232142 0.2453835 0.19393085 0.31232142
[5,] 0.02940105 0.3807457 0.11235120 0.3123214 1.00000000 0.8852339 0.24538346 0.14648918
[6,] 0.30942406 0.6631172 0.31232142 0.2453835 0.88523391 1.0000000 0.31232142 0.56136321
[7,] 0.02940105 0.1912670 1.00000000 0.1939309 0.24538346 0.3123214 1.00000000 0.04206641
[8,] 0.30942406 0.8845494 0.03038282 0.3123214 0.14648918 0.5613632 0.04206641 1.00000000
```

These data are different to those reported by STATISTICA (but similair to exact values in last column). When the *continuity correction* is nulled `correct=FALSE`, the output of the above code is the same as the *adjusted* column p-values given my STATISTICA.

```
 > d<-my.data
> groups <- unique( d$group )
> MWU<-outer( 
+   groups, groups, 
+   Vectorize( function(g1,g2) {
+     wilcox.test( 
+       d$value[ d$group == g1 ], 
+       d$value[ d$group == g2 ],
+       paired=FALSE,
+       exact=FALSE,
+       correct=FALSE
+     )$p.value
+   } )
+ )
> 
> MWU
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]       [,7]
[1,] 1.00000000 1.0000000 0.02016457 0.24538346 0.02016457 0.2453835 0.02016457
[2,] 1.00000000 1.0000000 0.18858231 1.00000000 0.30649217 0.5613632 0.14648918
[3,] 0.02016457 0.1885823 1.00000000 0.08326452 0.08326452 0.2482131 1.00000000
[4,] 0.24538346 1.0000000 0.08326452 1.00000000 0.24821308 0.1912670 0.14891467
[5,] 0.02016457 0.3064922 0.08326452 0.24821308 1.00000000 0.7728300 0.19126699
[6,] 0.24538346 0.5613632 0.24821308 0.19126699 0.77282999 1.0000000 0.24821308
[7,] 0.02016457 0.1464892 1.00000000 0.14891467 0.19126699 0.2482131 1.00000000
[8,] 0.24538346 0.7715034 0.02092134 0.24821308 0.11021018 0.4678251 0.02940105
           [,8]
[1,] 0.24538346
[2,] 0.77150341
[3,] 0.02092134
[4,] 0.24821308
[5,] 0.11021018
[6,] 0.46782508
[7,] 0.02940105
[8,] 1.00000000
```

However, as i understand, due to the small sample size, ties are inevitable with discrete data, and are presented in the original data. Therefore, to account for these ties, `correct=TRUE`is correct. When `correct=TRUE` the output, as above, are similiar to the **2*1 sided, exact** *p* column reported by STATISTICA, but not identical.

Guidance by STATISTICA is given here: http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=Nonparametrics/NonparametricAnalysis/Dialogs/StartupPanel/NonparametricsStatisticsStartupPanelMannWhitneyUtest

It seems, though, that whilst a small sample size would result in reporting **2*1 sided, exact** *p* values, it does not assume ties. So i do not feel the data comply to this.

Based on the above example, am i correct to assume that *continuity correction* is the correct approach due to ties, and that the **2*1 sided, exact** *p* values in statistica are those to be reported?

Please also comment on R code - is it appropriate for `correct=TRUE` when two samples that are compared to do not contain ties?

Answer (score 1):

Minimum sample sizes for a traditional Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank sum test (with no tied data)
to show significance at the 5% level are $n_1 = n_2 = 4.$
The minimal P-value $2/{8 \choose 4} = 0.0286$ can be achieved only
when there is complete separation between groups (all observations in one
group are smaller than any observation in the other). So in this entire
experiment you are working right at the edge of being able to see significant
results, and not.

Between T3 & T8 you have complete separation, so the exact P-value from the
R function `wilcox.test` is 0.0286. As follows:

```
t3 = c(75, 66, 25, 21);  t8 = c(14, 8, 20, 15)
wilcox.test(t3, t8)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  t3 and t8
W = 16, p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Between T1 & T3, T1 & T5, and T1 & T7 you have complete separation, but
the tied observations in T1 lead to an approximated P-value 0.0294
(roughly, but not exactly, what you have in your tables).

```
 t1 = c(10, 9, 11, 10)
 wilcox.test(t1, t3) 

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  t1 and t3
W = 0, p-value = 0.0294
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(t1, t3) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

I suppose STATISTICA uses one of several statistical programs that purport to give
an 'exact' P-value where the traditional MWW test does not (owing to ties); those values,
which you show in red. are slightly different depending on the nature of the ties. With or without 'exact' corrections, the pairs with complete separation
are the only ones with P-values below 5%. Various software packages have somewhat different ways of dealing with small sample sizes and with ties; I would not
endorse one over the other. Perhaps others on this site have strong preferences, which they are no doubt willing to express. (My favorite method of handling data that do not satisfy the conditions of a traditional MWW signed rank test is to use a permutation test instead.)

Now let's look at a permutation test for one of the 'borderline' results in
your table, specifically, T3 & T4, for which your approximated (red) P-value is about 0.08.

We use the pooled two-sample t statistic as a 'metric' for the
permutation test. We are *not* assuming this statistic has the
distribution $\mathsf{T}(df = 6)$ because we are not willing to assume
the data are normal. But we are assuming this test statistic is
a valid way to measure the 'distance' between T3 and T4.

Then we simulate
the permutation distribution by looking at 100,000 instances in which
values in T3 and T4 are randomly swapped between two groups. Then
we judge whether the observed value 2.338 of the t statistic is extreme when
compared to the simulated permutation distribution.

```
t3 = c(75,66,25,21);  t4 = c(0, 2, 3, 33)
all = c(t3, t4);  gp = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2)
t.obs = t.test(all~gp, var.eq=T)$stat
set.seed(813);  m = 10^5
t.prm = replicate( m, t.test(all ~ sample(gp))$stat )
mean(abs(t.prm)> abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.05803   # P-value of simulated permutation test
```

The observed value of the pooled t statistic is $T_{obs} = 2.338;$ the
(unrelaible) P-value of a pooled t test is 0.058. The P-value of the
permutation test is 0.058 (surprisingly not much different from the actual
t test). The permutation test has a smaller P-value than the approximated
P-value of the MWW rank sum test.

The figure below compares the permutation distribution with 
$\mathsf{T}(df=6).$ The distributions are clearly not the same, but
their tails happen to have similar probabilities--for the particular data in T3 and T4. The vertical red bars
are at $\pm T_{obs}.$

[image]

*Notes:* (a) There were 66 uniquely different values of the t statistic encountered in the permutation test shown here. That should be enough to get
an accurate P-value. (b) In the permutation test, we could have used the Welch (separate
variances) t test; the t statistics would be exactly the same (because sample sizes
are equal), but we could not have shown a hypothetical t distribution because
the degrees of freedom would be different for each permutation of the data. (c) The difference in sample means (numerator of the t statistic) could have been used as the metric with a very similar P-value, but then a direct comparison with
the t test would not be possible. (d) For a basic treatment of permutation tests using R, see [Eudey et al. (2010)](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n1/eudey.pdf). Sect. 3 discusses two-sample tests.

Comment: Hi @BruceET,

Thank you for your input. I had not considered permutation tests, specifically two-sample, and after further reading it seems one of the correct methods. 
I am curious if there is a more efficient way of calculating permutation results.

I have been toying with ::Coin package, specifically 'independence_test()'. I used the same data as 'T3' & 'T4' -

'independence_test(group~value, data=T3T4)'
Z= -1.8268, p-value = 0.06773

As i understand, 'independence_test' through ::coin is a two-sample permutation, so curious as to why the difference in p-values?

Comment: If by 'efficient' you mean less code, then there may be some libraries in R that have pre-programmed permutation tests, but then I don't know about flexibility in choosing models or metrics. If you mean 'faster running', then you could write a program that finds just the t statistic or just its numerator; using `t.test` wastes some time because internally R is formatting the entire output for each of $m$ tests, but I'm just picking off the t statistics from each test with \$-notation.

Comment: For your current project it is probably useless to look at comparisons among T's where there is overlap of more than one of 4 outcomes. With only 4 obs for each, no reasonable test will find highly significant results for them. // Probably start by ignoring comparisons where MWW gives P-value=1. // Also inefficient to look at both Tx & Ty and Ty & Tx, they are bound to give same P-value, not matter what correct 2-sided test you do. Also, no need to look at Tx & Tx.

Comment: Also should point out you are looking at ${8 \choose 2} = 28$ comparisons here. At the 5% level it wouldn't be surprising to find a couple of 'significant' results by chance alone. // Are you sure you shouldn't be using some kind of multiple comparison procedure with a 'family' error rate. Can't tell for sure from your brief description.

Comment: Thank you for your further comments. Re Multiple Comparisons, i have explored this previously, but due to the nature of the data (small samples, ND etc.) i settled with a NP MWU and code that would run each MWU (Tx v Ty ...) multiple times to produce a matrix of p-values. Earlier I ran a one-way sample permutation followed by pairwise permutation (https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_06a.html). The code i ran here accounts for False Discovery Rate ( i assume you are referring to by 'family' error rate). However, the outputs were not as expected. Unsure if i have answered your Q?